# What's the difference between fixture.componentInstance and fixture.debugElement.componentInstance in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

When performing unit tests with Angular, you usually use a `ComponentFixture` to get a reference of a component. The auto-generated unit-tests from the Angular CLI give you something like the following:

```
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
```

However, I can also use the `componentInstance` property directly on `fixture` like so:

```
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
const component = fixture.componentInstance; // note that I don't reference `debugElement` here
```

What's the difference between the two and when should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will give you much clearer picture: https://angular.io/guide/testing#debugelement

So, a short answer would be if you are running tests on a non-browser platform that doesn't have a DOM or whose DOM-emulation doesn't support the full HTMLElement API, then you MUST use `fixture.debugElement.componentInstance`, otherwise your tests would fail. Else, it doesn't matter, you can use either of those if you are using browser.

**Also:** `fixture.debugElement.componentInstance` gives `componentInstance` of type `any` 
whereas `fixture.componentInstance` gives you `componentInstance` of type `T`.